# How to use rvest's read_html to read a list of HTML files?

Tags: r, web-scraping

I have a list of web urls that are all the same page, just with different information.

Like this:

```
http://www.halfordsautocentres.com/autocentres/chesterfield
http://www.halfordsautocentres.com/autocentres/derby-london-road
http://www.halfordsautocentres.com/autocentres/derby-wyvern-way
```

Each one has a different address under the CSS selector     .store-details__address.

I have written the following code that outputs a the correct address for a single page:

```
derby <- read_html("http://www.halfordsautocentres.com/autocentres/derby-wyvern-way")
derby %>%
+   html_node(".store-details__address") %>%
+   html_text()
[1] "Unit 7, Wyvern Way, Wyvern Retail Park, Derby, DE21 6NZ"
```

How can I make read_html read a list of urls rather than just a single one?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use any looping strategy that you want: `for`, `lapply`, `purrr::map`.

```
require(rvest)
urls <- c("http://www.halfordsautocentres.com/autocentres/chesterfield",
          "http://www.halfordsautocentres.com/autocentres/derby-london-road",
          "http://www.halfordsautocentres.com/autocentres/derby-wyvern-way")
```

Base **R** using a `for` loop

```
out <- vector("character", length = length(urls))
for(i in seq_along(urls)){
  derby <- read_html(urls[i])
  out[i] <- derby %>%
    html_node(".store-details__address") %>%
    html_text()
}
```

Base **R** with `*apply`

```
urls %>% 
  lapply(read_html) %>% 
  lapply(html_node, ".store-details__address") %>% 
  vapply(html_text, character(1))
```

Here is a `tidyverse/purrr`

```
require(tidyverse)

urls %>% 
  map(read_html) %>% 
  map(html_node, ".store-details__address") %>% 
  map_chr(html_text)
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked well. I used the *apply function to do it - worked as expected!